# .htaccess: Authentication AND Redirect

Tags: .htaccess, authentication, redirect, http-status-code-301

I'm trying to redirect one of my domains to another one using .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule !^admin($|/) http://mydomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

As you can see, I don't want to redirect the given folder ("admin") because that directory actually has content.

The problem is that I have another .htaccess in that directory with this code:

```
AuthName "You must login"
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
```

When I visit the non-redirecting folder in my browser, it redirects to a 401.html page on mydomain.com.

How do I fix this? I want to redirect everything to mydomain.com, except the directory "admin" which requires auth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for a `R=401` or a `ErrorDocument 401` in the config files for your first domain. Something is setting a custom 401 page that is then matching against your rewrite rule and it's redirecting the browser to `mydomain.com`.

Answer (score 0):

A trap for the unwary is that your browser is probably caching your redirects during testing.  So when testing remove the 301 from R=301 to leave the R flag by itself.

Thus:

```
RewriteRule !^admin($|/) http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

Once you are happy with the workings of your htaccess redirect then change the R flag to R=301 (being a permanent redirect).

If you have been using R=301, then clear your browser's cache.